# Visualization of Standard Deviation in an array

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, deviation

As a python newbie I need a little help. 
I have an array with 100 rows and 100 columns. Each position stands for a temperature value. I now want to calculate the mean of the whole array (I have that so far) and then create a new array with the same dimension like the first one and with the standrard deviation at each positions. At the end I want to get an array with the deviation from the mean at each postion, so I want to know, how far each value spreads from the mean. I hope you understand what I mean? For better understanding: the array is an infrared thermography image of a house. With the calulation of standard deviation I want to get the best reactive/sensitive pixels in the image. Maybe someone has done something like this before. In the end I want to export the file, so that I get an image that is similar looking to the infrared image. But not with the raw temperatures but the standard deviation temperatures.

Importing the file and calculating the mean like this:

```
data_mean = []

my_array = np.genfromtxt((line.replace(',','.') for line in data),skip_header=9,delimiter=";")

data_mean.append(np.nanmean(my_array))
```

Then I need calculation the standard deviation of each position in the array.

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
data_mean = np.mean(my_array) #gets you the mean of the whole array
```

return an array where every value is the mean of your data

```
meanArray = np.ones(my_array.shape)*data_mean 

variationFromMean = my_array - meanArray
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: hey, thank you very much.  looks quiet good for now. If you could now only give me an advice how I can plot this new array as a new image it would be fantatistic. I would like to plot this in colours (I guess there is lots of ways to chose colours), so that my new output should look similar to the infrared image, but in colours that fit to the new values (so that in the end you can see how big the bariation from the mean is)? Thanks so much. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: this website goes over how to plot an image in matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html. If you look at the bottom it also goes over setting the color map to get hot colors. I think Tom Patel's answer below may be more statistically relevant because it shows you and array of how many standard deviations away the values are from the mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping the data in an array format here is a solution:

```
import numpy as np

#Find the mean of the array data values
mean_value = np.mean(data_mean)

#Find the standard deviation of the array data values
standard_deviation = np.std(data_mean)

#create an array consisting of the standard deviations from the mean
array = data_mean/standard_deviation
```